# How to align specific layout to bottom and fix size of imageview to cover remaining space?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a imageview & relative layout, where the layout containing two buttons should align to bottom and circular image should stretch to take remaining space. I tried from other answers but could not do it. I have code and image below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
android:clickable="true">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_child_with_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_child"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_child">
        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_SavedInvoice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/service_app_logo"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_inner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/iv_SavedInvoice"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    >
                    <Button
                        style="@style/PrimaryButton"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/form_proof_replace_invoice"
                        android:id="@+id/button_ReplaceInvoice" />
                    <Button
                        style="@style/NoBorderButton"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/form_proof_next"
                        android:id="@+id/button_SavedProofNext" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Align_Parent_Bottom]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you used ScrollView and other Nested Layout. The UI that you want can be simply achieved by using layout weight attribute. You check this code and make changes according to your need.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_child"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_child_with_progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_SavedInvoice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_inner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iv_SavedInvoice"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_ReplaceInvoice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="form_proof_replace_invoice" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_SavedProofNext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="form_proof_next" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks, scrollview was the culprit. Actually I have some other code inside scrollview which I haven't posted. I shifted above layout out of scrollview and it is working.

Comment: can you do me another little favour. I have used "fitXY" to fit height of image to cover height gap upto button. How can I maintain aspect ratio of landscape image and send width of image out of screen?

Comment: Replate fitXY with centerCrop. It will maintain aspect ration. But it will crop some area. Try this if it is fine. Or can can try some library for ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

You should set <kbd>layout_height</kbd>   **match_parent** instead of  **wrap_content**.

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_inner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/iv_SavedInvoice"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    >
```

Secondly, Add **`android:fillViewport="true"`** in your <kbd>ScrollView</kbd> Section .

Comment: That will expand height of linearlayout containing buttons. I want height of ll_inner to be static. I want height/width of the image to be dynamic here. I tried and didn't work.

Comment: @BinodLama Add `android:fillViewport="true"` in ScrollView Section

Comment: @BinodLama Remove `android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"`